# TIS Services: selecting Czech

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, localization

I'm trying to change system input language after focusing on a NSTextField. I have 3 input languages in system: English, Russian and Czech (QWERTY).

I use this method:

```
TISInputSourceRef ref = TISCopyInputSourceForLanguage(CFSTR("cs"));
TISSelectInputSource(ref);
```

And it works great with Russian, but not with Czech... The Czech language tag is `cs`, Russian - `ru`. Two hours ago I made the output

```
NSLog("%@", ref);
```

print something about Czech but now it prints only `(null)`. I want to use exactly QWERTY, not QWERTZ, but I really can not find anywhere the tag, that represents Czech QWERTY layout. The Apple Documentation says:

> If more than one such input source exists and at least one has been
>   used, the most recently used input source is chosen.

But it always chooses English, not Czech! And in the console, as I've said before, it prints `(null)`... So what must I use to choose Czech? I've lost about 3 hours doing this... Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that `TISCopyInputSourceForLanguage()` isn't behaving as expected. You should file a bug report with Apple.

There are some workarounds, but first: have you tried setting the `allowedInputSourceLocales` property of the text field cell? Since that specifies a locale, I'm not sure if it will restrict input to just Czech, select a Czech input source, or select the Czech-QWERTY input source in particular, but it's worth a try.

If that doesn't help, then I'd write fallback code for when `TISCopyInputSourceForLanguage()` fails. Copy the list of all enabled keyboard layout input sources and search it for one which supports Czech as a language.

```
TISInputSourceRef ref = TISCopyInputSourceForLanguage(CFSTR("cs"));

if (!ref)
{
    NSDictionary* properties = @{ (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceCategory: (__bridge NSString*)kTISCategoryKeyboardInputSource,
                                  (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceType: (__bridge NSString*)kTISTypeKeyboardLayout,
                                  (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceIsSelectCapable: @YES,
                                  };
    NSArray* sources = CFBridgingRelease(TISCreateInputSourceList((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties, NO));
    for (id sourceObj in sources)
    {
        TISInputSourceRef source = (__bridge TISInputSourceRef)sourceObj;
        NSArray* langs = (__bridge NSArray*)TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages);
        if ([langs containsObject:@"cs"])
        {
            ref = source;
            break;
        }
    }
}

TISSelectInputSource(ref);
```

You could extend this by looking for the source for which "cs" comes earliest in the language array (in case multiple sources support it).

Even this doesn't guarantee that you'll get the QWERTY variant of Czech input sources. If you really want that one, specifically, you should maybe use its input source ID, which is "com.apple.keylayout.Czech-QWERTY".

To find that one, you would use:

```
NSDictionary* properties = @{ (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceID: @"com.apple.keylayout.Czech-QWERTY" };
NSArray* sources = CFBridgingRelease(TISCreateInputSourceList((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties, NO));
TISInputSourceRef source = (__bridge TISInputSourceRef)sources.firstObject;
```

However, you should be prepared for that input source to not be enabled or even, perhaps, installed. (Apple may change its Czech-QWERTY layout to use a different identifier or something.) If it's installed but not enabled, you can find it by adding code like the following after the above code:

```
if (!source)
{
    properties = @{ (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceID: @"com.apple.keylayout.Czech-QWERTY",
                    (__bridge NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceIsEnableCapable: @YES };
    sources = CFBridgingRelease(TISCreateInputSourceList((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties, YES));
    source = (__bridge TISInputSourceRef)sources.firstObject;

    if (source && TISEnableInputSource(source) != noErr)
        source = NULL;
}
```

Mind you, enabling an input source without the user's permission is user-hostile.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works great if I use inputSourceID! 

P. S. I write this app only for me to enter Czech-Russian cards to learn new words. So it's very useful if the lang changes automatically. And again: thank you!